# How do you get console to work in Notepad++ v7.7.1 (32-bit)?

Tags: html, notepad++

I keep on getting an error message any time I try and run a command in Notepad++'s console.
I am using HTML and I tried running `<h1>Starting and Ending code</h1>` and this is what I got. It did this with other lines of code as well. [The error message I keep on getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKA1e.png)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to plug HTML syntax into a Bash terminal. What do you expect a console to "run" in HTML. HTML isn't a programming language; it's instructions for marking up text. A console can no more "run" a markup language than it can run a banana.

Comment: Silvio, should it also happen with Python? Asking as this also happens when I try using python (doing things like the simple print("hello world"))

Comment: Have you told the console to run Python? Generally a console is running a shell language, most commonly Bash (or cmd on Windows), not Python